# Functional urban areas in the UK

Tags: data, united-kingdom

I want to perform an analysis on **urban areas** **in the UK**. As, indeed, urban areas can be defined in multiple ways, I would like to rely on some well-accepted definitions and polygons.

I found this [EU project](http://database.espon.eu/db2/home) that has nice data about functional urban areas in the Union, but the source data is rather old (2000).

Then I found [UK city regions](https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/populationandmigration/populationestimates/articles/populationdynamicsofukcityregionssincemid2011/2016-10-11), one of the many admin units in the UK, but I can't find shapefiles for them (and they look very large).

Moreover, I would like to find a **point dataset with cities and towns** (a gazetteer) in the UK, with population information in order to use them as labels dynamically (e.g., show cities > 1M, etc.). The OS Open Names product is way too detailed, and does not seem to contain a handy categorisation between small and large centres.

Any tips?

Comment: If you are after open data then the place to ask your question may be the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through their [Open Geography Portal](http://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/) ONS provide downloads of boundaries of Urban Audit Boundaries / Functional Urban Areas as well as a seperate Built-Up areas dataset. The latter I think is for England/Wales only although you can get a Settlements/Localities dataset for Scotland from National Records of Scotland [here](https://www.nrscotland.gov.uk/statistics-and-data/geography/our-products/settlements-and-localities-dataset)

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you! Would you happen to know also where to find some point datasets of cities, excluding the usual GeoNames?

Comment: As an alternative to OS Open Names there is the older (now deprecated) OS 1:50,000 gazetteer. It includes a FeatureType attribute e.g. City / Town etc. OS have now deprecated the dataset but the most recent version that was released it available from the [mySociety open data cache](http://parlvid.mysociety.org/os/)